# How to add a SQLServer Full Text Search in Django?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, full-text-search, rawsql

In Django, one can use full text search natively when using Postgres. However, when using it with SQL Server (and django-pyodbc-azure) there is no simple way to do it (as far I know).

To do a full text search in SQL Server you use the `CONTAINS(column, word)` function as described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017), but Django ORM contains do: `LIKE '% text %'`.

I did find two alternative methods to bypass this problem. One is using RAW SQL the other is using django [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

Snippet using django raw SQL:

```py
sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(text_field, 'term')"
table = Table.objects.raw(sql)
```

Using django extra:

```py
where = "CONTAINS(text_field, 'term')"
table = Table.objects.extra(where=[where])
```

There is two problems with it:

- Raw queries are harder to mantain.
- Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra).  recommend against using the extra method.

So I want to know if there a better way to do this, using "pure" django ORM if possible.